# Use apply with a method in Hugo

Tags: hugo

I don't know if the terminology is correct, but essentially it comes down to using something like `site.GetPage` or `path.Base` as opposed to something like `humanize` with `apply` in Hugo:

I have a part of a layout in Hugo that looks like the following:

```
{{ range .Params.related_plays }}
{{ with site.GetPage . }}<li><a href="{{.Permalink}}">{{.Title}}</a></li>{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

where `related_plays` is a list of strings containing the path to pieces of content (e.g. `["english/play-1.md", "english/play-2.md"]`. This currently works.

Instead of the above, I'd like to assign the list of page objects into a variable. I've tried something like the following:

```
{{ $related_plays := apply .Params.related_plays "site.GetPage" "." }}
```

but I get the following error:

```
error calling apply: can't find function site.GetPath
```

Is there any way to call `apply` for something like this?

I'm guessing my alternative is to build up a `Scratch` slice via the `range` and `with` functions, but if it can be done with `apply`, I would prefer that.